# how to upload my image to another computer that shared a folder Images with my computer

Tags: php

I want to upload my image to another computer that shared a folder Images with my computer.
This is image's path:

```
//92.62.178.149/Documents/Images
```

This is my code:

```
chmod ("//92.62.178.149/Documents/Images/", 0777);
move_uploaded_file($tmpname, "//92.62.178.149/Documents/Images/" . $str . "." . $type);
```

But I got some warnings:

> Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\2new\ClassImage.php on line 66
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(//92.62.178.149/Documents/Images/d8426230-5a36-11e2-b0bc-616263646566.jpeg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\2new\ClassImage.php on line 68
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php782.tmp' to '//92.62.178.149/Documents/Images/d8426230-5a36-11e2-b0bc-616263646566.jpeg' in C:\xampp\htdocs\2new\ClassImage.php on line 68

Comment: I'm assuming your path is a SMB share?

Comment: have to use this ?????: smb://ServerName/ShareName
    smb://DOMAIN;User@ServerName/ShareName

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$destinationFolder = "\\\\92.62.178.149\\Documents\\Images\\";
chmod ($destinationFolder , 0777);
move_uploaded_file($tmpname, $destinationFolder  . $str . "." . $type);
```

Note:-

```
When you are running a PHP script from the browser, you are not running it under your 
user account. You are running under whatever the HTTP server uses as the user name. 
So even if you have access to the folder, the server may not. 
The easiest fix is to give the serverwrite permission to that folder.
```